# How to filter the retrieved items using a pnp.sp.web REST call to a SharePoint list

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I want to filter an SP list which my form is retrieving items from. The list has two columns Title, Start Date. I want to retrieve the start date items but dates that are either today or 21 days into the future.

I have this already:

```
 public _getMeetings() {
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Meetings").items.filter("StartDate What here?! eq 'WHAT HERE?!'").get().then((items: any[]) => {
      let returnedPMeetings: IDropdownOption[] = items.map((item) => { return { key: item.StartDate, text: item.StartDate }; });
      this.setState({ MeetingsList: returnedPMeetings });
    });
  }
```

As you can see I've got something in the filter arguments but I don't know how to achieve the specific filter I need. There are no decent resources on the syntax required for filtering that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter by date:

```
public _getMeetings() {
    let today = new Date();
    let futureDate = new Date();
    let offsetDays = 21;
    futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + offsetDays, futureDate.getMonth(), futureDate.getFullYear());
    var filterString = `StartDate ge datetime'${today.toISOString()}' and StartDate le datetime'${futureDate.toISOString()}'`;
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Meetings").items.filter(filterString).get().then((items: any[]) => {
        let returnedPMeetings: IDropdownOption[] = items.map((item) => { return { key: item.StartDate, text: item.StartDate }; });
        this.setState({ MeetingsList: returnedPMeetings });
    });
}
```

**Edit 1**

You can try a CamlQuery like that:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Ge>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today />
                </Value>
            </Ge>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today OffsetDays="21" />
                </Value>
            </Leq> 
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

I hope this helps,

greetings Joe!

For more SharePoint related informations look [here](https://www.smarterbusiness.at/smarter-blog)

Comment: Hi Joe, that seems overly complicated to me. Is there nothing simpler?
If it's the most simple solution, then perhaps you can talk me through it?

Comment: Hey! Why is this complicated to you? The only complicated thing here is to set the future date to 21 days ahead! If you want to stick with odata queries, this is the way to go! If you want so go with a CamlQuery, there is another way!

Comment: Check my edit, this is a possible way with a caml query!

Comment: Hi J,
Can you explain the 'le' in this part:
and StartDate le datetime

Comment: Hey, that means 'less than or equal' which is the same as `<=` and the same goes for 'ge' means 'greater than or equal' which is the same as `>=`! But to see all ODATA URI conventions look here https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/